# python check if letter part of word in string

Tags: python

I want to write a function which checks whether a letter is part of a word e.g

```
"u" part of word in "i c u" = false
"u" part of word in "umbrella" = true
```

Comment: define "word". Is "a" a word?

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> text = "i c u"
>>> letter = "u"
>>> any(letter in word and len(word) > 1 for word in text.split())
False
>>> text = "umbrella"
>>> any(letter in word and len(word) > 1 for word in text.split())
True
```

You might change `letter in word` to `letter.lower() in word.lower()` depending if you are case sensitive or nt.

Comment: @limelights It works as long as it is part of a word and not the whole thing as the examples imply

Comment: it wont work for lowercase 'i' either or any 1 letter words for that fact, even though there are very few.

Comment: Until the author supplies more test cases, how to handle single letter words is ambiguous. It is implied that the word must have two or more letters to be count as a word from the example given, and this handles the test cases given.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean 'in a word' to be 'has at least one character on either side that is a "word character"', this would work:

```
import re
def letter_in_a_word(letter, words):
    return bool(re.search(ur'\w{0}|{0}\w'.format(letter), words))

letter_in_a_word('u', 'i c u') # False
letter_in_a_word('u', 'umbrella') # True
letter_in_a_word('u', 'jump') # True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> word = 'i c u'
>>> letter = 'u'
>>> letter in word.split(' ')
True
>>> word = 'umbrella'
>>> letter in word.split(' ')
False
```